# Is this graph 4-critical?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to do the next problem

---

Let $G$ be the $4$-regular graph derived from the cartesian product of a triangle $x_1x_2x_3x_1$ and a path $y_1y_2y_3y_4y_5$ by identifying the vertices $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_1, y_5)$, $(x_2, y_1)$ and $(x_3, y_5)$, and $(x_3, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_5)$. Show that $G$ is $4$-critical.

---

I don't know how to do it, is it necessary to verify that every subgraph of $G$ is $3$-critical? or is there any form to do it directly?
thanks!

Comment: Critical with respect to which property?